# SharePoint Framework ( SPFx) is it possible to create custom HTML page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, office-365-developer

Just started learning SPFx, so had many queries. First of all

In **SharePoint** **Framework** ( **SPFx**) is it possible to create custom HTML page and make that as default landing page for add in.

So that we don't have to use Typescript for the simple things that can be achieved using simple **JS** and **HTML**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SPFx webpart solution works like on-premise visual web part, it need host in one page(classic page or modern page), so there is no 'welcome' page like SharePoint add-in solution.

For your requirement, I suggest you check [SPFx react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor), you could insert HTML/script to this webpart like script editor webpart.

Comment: Thanks. Can we add out javascript code to newly created .js file and refer that in .ts file.
Like  for e.g. we can define Jquery's .click function in file?

Comment: For custom js, check https://blog.mastykarz.nl/migrate-sharepoint-javascript-customizations-sharepoint-framework-reference-functions/, for jQuery, you could check official demo https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part.